# Address case sensitivity in Django

Tags: django

Let's say I have an app named `TaskDashboard`. Yes, I know that the best practice is to give names for packages in lower case. But let's say that I can't change that.

Then I want to generate some docs using the built-in Django mechanisms. I wrote the following docstring for a model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    """
    Every task is linked to a :model:`TaskDashboard.Column`.
    """
```

That allows to form the links to related models in the documentation. However, when I click on that, I get to the lower cased address `/.../taskdashboard.column` and get 404 error. If I change the address to `/.../TaskDashboard.column/` I get the proper page.

How to solve the problem with case sensitivity without changing the app name?

Answer (score 1):

Change [**`AppConfig.label`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) in app config

```
#TaskDashboard/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class TaskdashboardConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'TaskDashboard'
    label = 'taskdashboard'
```

and specify this new config class in **`INSTALLED_APPS`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'TaskDashboard.apps.TaskdashboardConfig',
    # other apps
]
```